# Drag and drop bug reporting tool/software

Tags: reporting, spreadsheet, drag-drop

Currently, my clients are using excel/Google Sheets to report their issues & encountered bugs when they are using the delivered Android APKs.

I'm looking for the fastest alternative reporting tool/software for them to make the creation of their feedbacks as fast as possible and not boring at the same time, because the main issue with excel is that the captured screenshots are not coming aligned in their respective cells, and the process of inserting picture is tedious even for Google Sheets it take too long to work with IMAGE("") function with stored screenshots on Drive. I've tried some excel add-on (Excel Image Assistant) but looking for a simple drag & drop from desktop to report.

## Expected features:

- Drag & Drop feature, take image from desktop and put it inside a fixed place in the report.
- Export to at least one known file format: HTML, XLSX...
- Easy to use for every person.
- Create multiple columns with custom headers.
- Able to manage font type, color & size.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From your tags it looks like it must be an Android app, and the result must be an Excel sheet. Is that correct? So a web-based issue tracker won't fit the purpose, even if it had a companion Android app?

Comment: it's not an obligation to find an Android App, and also not forcibly it should export to excel, just searching for the fastest possible to push productivity of the clients by finding an easy to use drag and drop tool from desktop inside the report, even if it's a web based issue tracker.

Comment: In that case, while waiting for good answers, you might wish to check with our [answered issue-tracker questions](/search?q=[issue-tracker]+answers%3A1). As tags mark mandatories, I've removed the `android` and `microsoft-excel` tags. Your description still holds the facts, so it's not lost :) Good luck!